# I want to compare date of duration of leaves with the current date in odoo python

Tags: python, date, datetime, odoo, odoo-10

Here is the program which i wrote and inherited from **hr.holidays** 
that if the selected date is before the current date then it should provide an error message.
Code-

```
from datetime import date

if self.date_from <= date.today():
            print 'You cannot select the previous date'
```

But it gives the error-

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to bool
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hello Ujjwal Singh Baghel,**

Try this below code,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime
i = datetime.datetime.now()

print ("Current date & time = %s" % i)


if self.date_from <= str(i):
            print 'You cannot select the previous date'
```

OR

```
from datetime import date
if self.date_from <= str(date.today()):
            print 'You cannot select the previous date'
```

## For example

```
from datetime import date
if "10/07/2017" <= str(date.today()):
            print 'You cannot select the previous date'
```

**Out put:**

> You cannot select the previous date

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comments, please.